# Conditional IF doesn't match

Tags: vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding the IF conditional and I am wondering if you can help me to resolve it.

I have two Sheets;

- Sheet 1 – one table (TbAssign)
- Sheet 2 (Inventory) – one table (InventoryDetailTbl)
- I have created a macro to copy and paste some columns from Sheet 2 to Sheet1.  When the condition is “Triage” on Column #33. The macro is working well. No issues with this (Move the rows with “Triage” to Sheet1).
- The issue I have is when the Condition doesn’t match (Column #33 does not contain the word “Triage Triage”, therefore, the macro copies all rows to sheet1,
- I have tried to write a code an IF condition but is not working.

Could you please help me understand how I can write this macro when the condition is not matching?

```
Sub Update_Inventory()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrow As Long
Dim dstar As Double
dstar = Timer

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    lrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = lrow + 1

    Worksheets("Inventory").Select

    ***' I have tried to write a line macro IF condition

        'IF ActiveSheet.Range("InventoryDetailTbl['#33]").Value = "Triage" Then***

          With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("InventoryDetailTbl")
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=33, _
                Criteria1:="Triage"
            Union(.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange, _
             .ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange, _
             .ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange, _
             .ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange, _
             .ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange).Copy
         End With

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("D" & lrow).PasteSpecial

        Else

        MsgBox "There isn't new items to move"


        End if

         Worksheets("Inventory").Select

            With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("InventoryDetailTbl")
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=33
            End With


        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Try : Criteria1:="<>Triage"

Comment: @DisplayName I think the OP is trying to describe that his macro is copying all rows after the filter. He needs to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy`